# JavaScript undefined when using call()

Tags: javascript

```
obj = {}

obj.a = function(a) {
    console.log(a); // returns undefined
    //console.log('Obj.a')
}
    
obj.b = function(a) {
    console.log(a); // returns undefined
    //console.log('Obj.b')
}

var node = {
    a: {
        use:'a',
        node:[
            {
                create:'item',
                description:{name:'Samsung'},
            }
        ]
    },
    b: {
        use:'b',
        node:[
            {
                create:'item',
                description:{name:'Apple'},
            }
        ]
    }
  
}

for(name in node) {
    if(node.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        a = node[name];
        // console.log(name)
        obj[name].call(a)
    }
}
```

In the above code, why do I get `undefined` when calling functions obj.a and obj.b from the loop below, instead of the object that's being passed to it?

Comment: The first parameter will be the `this` value of the function and not an argument: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Actually, if I replace the `console.log(a)` inside the `obj.a` with `console.log(this)` I am able to see the object being passed. Is this correct behavior? It's all quite confusing to someone just beginning with JavaScript.

Comment: _"Is this correct behavior?"_ - Yes, as mentioned in my first comment (please, read the link)

Comment: Why did you accept the answer when you don't understand it?

Comment: @Andreas Because his solution worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). you should pass the object instance as first param

**According to the MDN**

> Note: In certain cases, thisArg may not be the actual value seen by the method.
> If the method is a function in non-strict mode, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be converted to objects.

```js
obj = {}

obj.a = function(a) {
  console.log(a); // returns undefined
  //console.log('Obj.a')
}

obj.b = function(a) {
  console.log(a); // returns undefined
  //console.log('Obj.b')
}

var node = {
  a: {
    use: 'a',
    node: [{
      create: 'item',
      description: {
        name: 'Samsung'
      },
    }]
  },
  b: {
    use: 'b',
    node: [{
      create: 'item',
      description: {
        name: 'Apple'
      },
    }]
  }

}

for (name in node) {
  if (node.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    a = node[name];
    // console.log(name)
    obj[name].call(obj,a)
  }
}
```

Comment: _"you should pass the object instance as first param"_ - Why?

Comment: And why is this an answer when reading the documentation of the `.call()` method would be enough (a.k.a research)?

Comment: @Andreas ""you should pass the object instance as first param" - Why? – Andreas 8 mins ago" What would it be according to you?

Comment: @Andreas I just point out mistake and target issue has mentioned with documentation. you are right already documented. But most of the search based on error. Also more useful to same error on future visitors